# How to get all of values from objects of interface Typescript 4.1.5

Tags: typescript

Hi so i have an interfaces for example

```
export interface A{
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

export interface B extends A{
  id: number;
  nameB: string;
}

export interface C {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  A: A,
  B: B
}
```

and i want to store object of type C as a string which will include all of values of this object . Basic Object.values(C) is returning string with two objects in it , so how to get all of this values ? Is there any other method to do this then taking object A from object C and object B of object C(which also include object A again)?

Comment: Those are not objects, because they are interfaces and interfaces do not exist at runtime. `Object.values` is a method to retrieve the values of an object at runtime. So if you want `Object.values` to work you need to create a class or an object literal.

Comment: Anyway , i have an object of type C ( i can't change this interface into class), and i want to get all of values from it .